# How to set --region with aws cli commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run the following command:

```
aws s3 cp --region ap-south-1 --acl public-read my.exe s3://bucket/binaries/my.exe
```

> upload failed: ./my.exe to s3://bucket/binaries/my.exe A client error
>   (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: You
>   are attempting to operate on a bucket in a region that requires
>   Signature Version 4.  You can fix this issue by explicitly providing
>   the correct region location using the --region argument, the
>   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable, or the region variable in the
>   AWS CLI configuration file.  You can get the bucket's location by
>   running "aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET".

How do I fix this error? I also tried the

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-south-1 aws s3 cp --acl public-read my.exe s3://bucket/binaries/my.exe
```

but with no luck.

```
# aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.28 Python/2.7.9 Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64 botocore/1.4.19
```

Comment: Can you add the output from `aws --version` to your question?

Comment: Added my version number. I am using Debian jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working after upgrading awscli.

```
pip install --upgrade awscli

aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.43 Python/2.7.9 Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64 botocore/1.4.33
```

Comment: Yes, AWS S3 needs upgraded A2S CLI for buckets in newer regions, since in newer regions, S3 doesn't support lower signature versions.

Answer (score -1):

(type on cli):
aws configure
(it will let you update keys,secret keys,region,output-format)